# Unable to set background image using python (2.7.3), bash and gnome3

Tags: python, bash

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
bashCommand = "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/{me}/autowallpaperchanger/" + pic_name
print bashCommand
os.system(bashCommand)
```

Print result:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/{me}/autowallpaperchanger/wallpaper-1252048.jpg
```

Copying and pasting the print result into a terminal makes the change successfully, so the command is correct, but os.system isn't processing the request correctly for some reason.

Thank you!

EDIT
Full script:
http://pastebin.com/bUKYYrn1

Comment: Does python run as its own user or under the id of the invoking user? Just a shot in the dark here but perhaps that's where your trouble is coming from?

Comment: try using raw strings bashCommand = r"..."

Comment: @Wysek: If copying and pasting the output works, this is not the isuue.  Morover, there is no back slash in the string, so no reason for a raw string anyway.

Comment: @SvenMarnach You are right, I was sure I saw a back slash there...

Comment: Very weird problem because os.system() prints out the response the OS sends to requests that you don't have rights for. Strange that it is just failing silently.

Comment: Full script here:

http://pastebin.com/bUKYYrn1

Comment: @IamChuckB I've posted the full script because I don't actually know the answer to your question. Sorry :/

Answer (score 1):

Using raw string works.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
bashCommand = r"gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/{me}/autowallpaperchanger/" + pic_name
print bashCommand
os.system(bashCommand)
```

The right way to do in python is

```
from gi.repository import Gio

SCHEMA = 'org.gnome.desktop.background'
KEY = 'picture-uri'

def change_background(filename):
    gsettings = Gio.Settings.new(SCHEMA)
    gsettings.set_string(KEY, "file://" + filename)
    gsettings.apply()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    change_background("/home/{me}/autowallpaperchanger/pic_name")
```